# Error in reading from Firebase Error: ValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read from a firebase database using code [straight from their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data). I have my code below and I see the following error when I try to add the `ValueEventListener` to the my `Firebase reference` variable.

> addValueEventListener (com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener) in Query cannot be applied to (com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener)

I am confused why this error occurs because following is the `import` statement I use at the top of my Java class file.

> import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

Basically, I am just trying to get basic read from Firebase running. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void readfromFireDB() {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://my_project.firebaseio.com/");

    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Question qn = postSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                mLog.printToLog("RECEIVED DATA = " + qn.getAnswer() + "," + qn.getLevel());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mLog.printToLog("in onCancelled, database error = " + databaseError.toString());
        }
    };

    ref.addValueEventListener(postListener); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS

}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Still having the same issue eve after using the entire classname: `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener postListener = new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() { ... }`

[image]

Comment: Try to fully qualify the class name: `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener postListener = new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() { ... }` and see if that resolves this issue.

Comment: Still getting an error. Updated the question with the error i see. It's as it my `ref` variable is expecting a `com.google.firebase.client.ValueEventListener` instead of a `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener`

Comment: If you start from this link "install firebase sdk" https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
and then here "get started with firebase databse" https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/  follow every instruction and reach the Link you've given "Retrieving Data"(after 3pages) you will never run in problem like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing classes from the legacy SDK (2.X) with the new SDK (9.X).  [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/) is legacy, [ValueEventListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) is new.

To use the new SDK, all of your imports should begin with `com.google.firebase.database`.

Legacy imports begin with `com.firebase.client`.

I'm assuming you want to use the new SDK.  If so, your module build.gradle dependencies should include:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
```

and should *not* include:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
```

Comment: The main `Firebase` reference i have this: `import com.firebase.client.Firebase;`. Is this wrong? This is the only option I get with the Alt+Enter key when I add the Firebase Reference.

Comment: `Firebase` is not used in the new SDK, replaced by [FirebaseDatabase](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase) and [DatabaseReference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference).